# How to organise files inside a folder in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, css, jsp, url, netbeans

I want to keep all CSS files in one folder and I want to access them. Below is the path of my CSS folder

`css/sampl.css`. Where `css` is the folder.

This is my code:

```
<link href="/CSS/sampl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I can't access the `sampl.css` file. Could somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a context path in the URL. To prepend a context path you can use JSP EL

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/CSS/sampl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The `CSS` folder is in the web application root.

Comment: Thanks @Roman C, it solved my issue. Thanks for your timely help bro