# How to include properly a css file in jsp

Tags: eclipse, web-applications

I tried this :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" />
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/orWDjgK.png]

but the css won't apply. :(

Am i missing something obvious ?

EDIT :

Here is my jsp :

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log-in</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="login-card">
    <h1>Log-in</h1><br>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login">
  </form>

  <div class="login-help">
    <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you tried it?

Comment: In webbrowser it doesn't work

Comment: I tried to login in my web browser : http://localhost:8080/cacahuete/
The login page loads but not the css

Comment: @RomanC just update my knowledge could tell me why won't work?By seeing OP's question  it look  fine for me. it should load in login page?

Comment: Have a look at the page source in the browser, what is showing on the line where the `<link>` tag should be?

Comment: @Soora You are right according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26588335/573032) answer. What do you don't understand?

Comment: I have 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/cacahuete/css/style.css" /> 

in the code source.

Comment: Ok, then my answer works, what is showing when you click on the link?

Comment: Is that a valid file path on your server? What are you expecting `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` to produce?

Comment: It is a valid path (i think) since my pages shows. Just the css not loading.

the ${pageContext.request.contextPath} produces "/cacahuete" which is my project name.

Comment: @Soora Look at this the webpage is loading and showing correct path, but it still doesn't work in the browser. What did you like to ask me?

Comment: I never said it doesn't work, you said it. I said the css wasn't loading properly.

Comment: What do you mean by *the css wasn't loading properly*? Post the hole JSP.

Comment: @Roman C I meant your first reply which you answer the question.thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
```

try this, will work. In java it ma

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-    `<jsp:include page="style.css"/>`

Using the include directive should do the trick.

Comment: This will include the entire file inline,  which I don't think is what is needed.